# how to add path to image uploader plugin in ckeditor in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, ckeditor, codeigniter-3

I have added Image uploader plugin of ckeditor now can anyone please tell me how to add browse server path ? I am using Coedigniter and have kept the folder in assets.
 I have found something on internet which says you can add in

```
plugins->imageuploader->plugin.js
```

In plugin.js

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'imageuploader', {
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = 'ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader/imgbrowser.php';
    }
});
```

I have found these. Now When I click to add image and click on `Browse Server` it throws me 404 Not found.

I am even attaching an image to the problem.
[Image of a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIhRV.png)

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to this.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7sKQRGQp hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is jquery code that returns the path to ckeditor when selected file in file browser

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var funcNum = <?php echo $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'].';'; ?>
  $('#fileList-wrapper').on('click', 'img', function() {
    var fileUrl = $(this).attr('data-id');
    window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(funcNum, fileUrl);
    window.close();
  });
});
```

Here file php code for show files in file browser

```
<div id="fileList-wrapper">
<?php 
    $fileList = glob('assets/uploads/*');
    foreach($fileList as $fileName){
    ?>
        <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="<?= base_url().$fileName?>" data-id="<?= base_url().$fileName?>" width="140" height="120"/>
                        <br />
                        <?= $fileName ?>
                    </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
```

Here are js file need to addded into the file

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

You might need to add css styling